# Move Files from Multiple Folders to Multiple Folders in Azure Blob

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have a folder structure in Azure Blob like this

Container/app_archive/app1/app1.csv

Container/app_archive/app2/app2.csv

Container/app_archive/app3/app3.csv

Container/app_archive/app4/app4.csv

Container/app_archive/app5/app5.csv

....

Container/app_archive/app150/app150.csv

These needs to be moved to Container/app_archive/app1/YYYY/MM/DD/app1.csv

Container/app_archive/app2/YYYY/MM/DD/app2.csv

.....

Container/app_archive/app150/YYYY/MM/DD/app150.csv

Whenever any file is placed in any folder, it has to trigger and copy the files accordingly. Also I need to capture this information in an audit table like Source File Name, Source File Path, Destination File Path etc etc. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Do some research and then when you have a proper issue, come back to us.

Comment: Could you share your attempt and issue in your attempt?

Comment: I am able to do it for one single application, not for 150 applications at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Storage event triggers with Dataset parameters** for this like below.

First Give the Root container and Blob path ends with as .csv in Storage event trigger.

[image]

Create two pipeline parameters and assign the trigger values to those while creating trigger.

[image]

[image]

Now, create dataset parameters for folder name and file names for both source and sink datasets.

**Source:**

[image]

**Sink:**

[image]

**My pipeline JSON:**

```
 {

"name": "pipeline1",

"properties": {

"activities": [

{

"name": "Copy data1",

"type": "Copy",

"dependsOn": [

{

"activity": "Set variable1",

"dependencyConditions": [

"Succeeded"

]

}

],

"policy": {

"timeout": "0.12:00:00",

"retry": 0,

"retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,

"secureOutput": false,

"secureInput": false

},

"userProperties": [],

"typeProperties": {

"source": {

"type": "DelimitedTextSource",

"storeSettings": {

"type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",

"recursive": true,

"enablePartitionDiscovery": false

},

"formatSettings": {

"type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"

}

},

"sink": {

"type": "DelimitedTextSink",

"storeSettings": {

"type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"

},

"formatSettings": {

"type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",

"quoteAllText": true,

"fileExtension": ".txt"

}

},

"enableStaging": false,

"translator": {

"type": "TabularTranslator",

"typeConversion": true,

"typeConversionSettings": {

"allowDataTruncation": true,

"treatBooleanAsNumber": false

}

}

},

"inputs": [

{

"referenceName": "Source1",

"type": "DatasetReference",

"parameters": {

"filename": {

"value": "@pipeline().parameters.filename",

"type": "Expression"

},

"folderpath": {

"value": "@pipeline().parameters.path",

"type": "Expression"

}

}

}

],

"outputs": [

{

"referenceName": "target1",

"type": "DatasetReference",

"parameters": {

"sinkpath": {

"value": "@variables('var_path')",

"type": "Expression"

},

"sinkfilename": {

"value": "@pipeline().parameters.filename",

"type": "Expression"

}

}

}

]

},

{

"name": "Set variable1",

"type": "SetVariable",

"dependsOn": [],

"userProperties": [],

"typeProperties": {

"variableName": "var_path",

"value": {

"value": "@concat(split(pipeline().parameters.path,'/')[2],'/',formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy/MM/dd'),'/')",

"type": "Expression"

}

}

}

],

"parameters": {

"path": {

"type": "string"

},

"filename": {

"type": "string"

}

},

"variables": {

"var_path": {

"type": "String"

},

"var1": {

"type": "String"

}

},

"annotations": []

}

}
```

**Result when a file uploaded to app1 folder:**

[image]